# appengine service to service queries not working

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, urlfetch, google-iap

I followed those [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/appidentity/#asserting_identity_to_other_app_engine_apps)

I have an appengine where 2 services (let's call them `A` and `B`) are deployed. The appengine is configured with IAP. (Identity Aware Proxy)

I can't get `B` to query `A`. If I call it simply with `urlfetch.fetch`, the call get's redirected with a `302` to what seems to be a login a page. The call is not logged in `A` so it seems to be intercepted elsewhere.

From what I understand this should work...

Anyway, I tried a using an `Authorization` header like we need to do when we want to query a google API. Still no luck, then I get a `401` with `{'www-authenticate': 'Bearer error="invalid id token"'}`

What should I do? Must I use a key? Activate an API switch somewhere to allow inter-services communications?

Also, they mention `X-Appengine-Inbound-Appid` needing to be there. How can I know if it's being added automatically or not? I set `follow_redirects` to false as the doc mentions it but I don't know how to see the outgoing traffic to confirm whether it's working or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things need to be done.

1. In the IAP config page, you need to allow the app itself. So, in the right pane, click "Add", and add the app. (Something like `<app-id>@appspot.gserviceaccount.com`)
2. You need to add the proper `"Authorization" : "Bearer <>"` header to the requests. You can follow [Authenticating from a service account](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/authentication-howto) to get the `token_response['id_token']` to put in the header. And yes, it's quite a lot of code.

Note that even though I added the new access, it's still not being displayed in the right pane. It may be related to the fact that IAP is still in beta.